# Can you use Index/Match to sum up filtered values in a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to create a formula that would use index/match to sum up all the values in a table that match the value in a certain column. I am trying to use this instead of sum ifs because the real data table I am using is very large and the sum if formula is running slowly. I am told that an index function could potentially calculate what I need faster.

The code I have so far goes like:

```
=SUM(
  INDEX(
    'Data Table'!$F$1:$F$18
    ,IF
      (
        ISNUMBER(MATCH('Data Table'!$D$1:$D$18,'Criteria Constraint'!$B$5,0))
        ,MATCH(ROW('Data Table'!$D$1:$D$18),ROW('Data Table'!$D$1:$D$18),0)
        ,""
      )
    ,4
    )
  )
```

As of right now that '*ISNUMBER(...*' section of the formula is meant to return and array of only the row numbers that match the value in '*'Criteria Constraint'!$B$5*'. It does this but when that array is passed onto the index function above, the index function only returns corresponding result in the first row value of the array (even using Ctrl+Shft+Entr).

Is there any way I could modify this formula so that the index function returns an array of values?

**[Example Data: Trying to sum up count based on state criteria, $B$5 = TX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JIB9.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and what results you expect?

Comment: It is very unlikely that any combination of functions outperforms SUMIFS. I would urge you to try using a pivot table instead.